# Constructing a sentence with the phrase "the fact that a…”

Tags: phrase-usage, passive-voice

I have the following idea and I want to write them in a more formal way.

> From the derived model, the algorithm can recognize that this and this edge
>   are gutters but this and this are not. That mean that with the help of the
>   derived model, the algorithm can recognize whether any candidate edge
>   is a gutter or not.

I want to say this information starting with the “**The fact that a…**”

Here is my effort.

> The fact that a given edge is a gutter can be firmly and accurately
>   recognized from the derived models.

But I feel it does not clearly reflect my idea. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 4):

I think the primary problem you're having here is that a "fact" is, essentially, an undeniable, objective, observable truth.

In this example, however, you are using the model to determine whether or not a given edge is a gutter; that is, you're using the model to decide whether or not it is a fact.

While the statement is technically not *wrong*, one might reasonably assume that you mean that it is a fact that *any* given edge is a gutter, and the derived model proves this, rather than that if *a* given edge *factually is* a gutter, the model can accurately predict this.

In this particular case, I would avoid using "the fact that" at all. It would be more accurate and precise to say:

> "Whether or not a given edge is a gutter can be firmly and accurately recognized from the derived model."

However, personally, given the vague and figurative meaning of the word "firmly", and given the nature of "recognized" as a verb that needs, generally speaking, a human agent capable of making subjective observations (as well as a few other nitpicks: there's a split infinitive, and I have a personal preference towards verbs other than "is" in formal writing), if I were to write it, I would phrase it as:

> "Whether or not a given edge qualifies as a gutter can be determined accurately with the derived model."

I hope that helps!

Comment: +1 I've tidied up OP's grammar, which I think distracts from the central question, so you may want to edit to reflect that.

Comment: I suggest that determination is effected not *by* the model but *with* or *by using* the model. The point of the passive voice in technical/scientific writing is to banish the Agent from the discourse. But when you use *by* you allow agency to creep back in, and falsely attribute it to the tool.

Comment: Isn't the implication that the algorithm (which I assumed to be intrinsically involved in the model; in all honesty, I'm not entirely clear on the context, nor am I particularly knowledgeable of the jargon) is the agent?

I will edit based on the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The construct was almost spot on: just remember that 'recognise' (sorry, I'm British, switch my 's' for a 'z' if necessary) should be a past participle.

"The fact that a given edge is a gutter can be firmly and accurately **recognised** from the derived models."

You would use this construct when you want to give emphasis on **the given edge**. If you wanted to put more emphasis on the 'derived model' you should use the first method: "From the derived model, the algorithm can recognise this...".

In general, you can split and stitch the statement around quite a bit, but whatever the sentence starts with is where the emphasis is.

Comment: Sort of .. The subject defines the topic, what is being talked about, where you are 'looking', but it is the *predicate* which provides the 'new information' and is therefore the strongest position in the sentence.